# Failed performance improvement in the nested for loop in openmp

Tags: c, openmp

I am doing the Eratosthenes Sieve algo to find prime numbers before n. Idea is to mark off all the multiples of a prime. However, it did not achieve a performance increase as the number of threads scale up.

It cost 0.009 seconds using 100 threads and 0.006 seconds using 1 thread to find the prime numbers before 100000.

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(t)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int index = 2; index <= N; index++) {
        list_of_nums[index - 2] = index;
    }

    #pragma omp for
    for (int loop_index = 2; loop_index <= num_to_stop; loop_index++) {
        if (list_of_nums[loop_index - 2] != -1) {
            for (int mark_index = loop_index - 2; mark_index < N - 1; mark_index += loop_index) {
                if (mark_index != loop_index - 2) {
                    if (list_of_nums[mark_index] % loop_index == 0) {
                        list_of_nums[mark_index] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pragma omp parallel for` ?

Comment: Maybe, @M.K.  The OP's `omp for` directives already appear inside a parallel section.

Comment: I believe your code is wrong. You are writing `list_of_nums` with multiple threads outside a critical section. A race condition might happen if `loop_index = 2` is taken care by thread1 and `loop_index =3`  by a different one as both might write into `loop_index[6] `

Comment: Using 100 threads is likely overkill.  For code that does not block, more threads than you have CPU cores provide no advantage.  But they *do* have *overhead*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes. I totally understand that. However, that is the most extreme condition we have to take care of for this project. Also, we are running a server, so I guess it is fine?

Comment: Your code is incorrect whether it gives you the correct result or not. Bad performance is actually a typical result of race conditions. That said, there's no point in parallelizing a code fragment that takes 6 ms *in isolation*.

Comment: @DavideSpataro You have a valid point. However, the code works fine. It can produce the output desired. The only problem is about the performance increase. It still added one condition if (list_of_nums[mark_index] % loop_index == 0 && list_of_nums[mark_index] != -1) to avoid the issue you are talking about.

Comment: @Zulan If I add #progma omp critical or atomic, would that hurt the performace even more?

Comment: @SkipperLin, "we are running a server" does not inherently make anything fine.  It just means that whatever issues your service may have have greater impact.  Your server *might* have 100+ cores, all available to be dedicated to this use, but it is more likely to have far fewer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see! Do you have any suggestion what the number of threads I should use given the user inputs the number of threads he/she wants to use?

Comment: @Zulan Also regarding the fact that there is no point of parallelizing this code, I could not agree more. However, the project is to do a prime number generator and a performance increase is expected. Do you have any suggestion how I improve the performance issue.

Comment: 1) Use larger problems, so the baseline time is significant. 2) Look through the many resources regarding parallel prime number generation on SO and the Internet in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, everything else notwithstanding, parallelization is not guaranteed to improve the speed of your program.  Managing multiple threads adds overhead to the computation, and that can overwhelm the speedup obtained by performing multiple computations concurrently.

Second, the scope for speedup is bounded by the amount of concurrency that can be achieved.  In particular, for computations that have no blocking operations, you cannot expect to see improvement from adding more threads than you have independent execution engines (roughly, cores).

But third, and here I will focus the rest of this answer, the Sieve of Eratosthenes has data dependencies that make it poorly suited for parallelization.  That you even get correct results from your parallel version arises from particular idiosyncrasies of your implementation.  The issue is focused here:

> ```
>         if (list_of_nums[loop_index - 2] != -1) {
> ```

That's checking whether `loop_index` has already been determined to be composite, so as to skip redundantly sieving out its multiples.  The keyword there is "already".  If `loop_index` *is* composite, and different threads than the current one were assigned to test its prime factors, then you cannot be confident that `loop_index` has already been *marked* composite.

You would be in trouble if you were choosing primes at that point and storing them in a separate list, as is common with SofE implementations.  Your particular implementation, on the other hand, is merely likely to do a lot of unnecessary work sieving out multiples of composites. Thus, not only do you have the overhead arising from managing multiple threads, but you are likely to be doing more total work.  It's not really the Sieve of Eratosthenes in that sense.

It is possible to write a parallel version of the SofE that correctly respects its data dependencies, though I'm uncertain whether OpenMP is rich enough to describe one.   I have done it in another language, and it did exhibit some speedup.  But properly respecting the dependencies greatly limits the amount of concurrency available (and adds *more* overhead), so the speedup was pretty lackluster.

### Update: possible alternatives

You know by measurement that your parallel approach has worse performance than the underlying serial one.  You can try to tweak parameters, such as the precise number of threads used, but you're probably better off going in a different direction.  Among the promising alternatives are:

- just use the serial version of your algorithm.  According to your measurement, that cuts run time by 33%, which is not shabby at all.
- pre-compute your sieve / prime list instead of computing it on the fly.  Then performance of the computation is not a factor in the performance of your larger service.
- pre-seed your sieve by marking multiples of several small primes, in parallel and accepting the redundancies involved, then run standard, serial SofE from there.  You would probably want to tune the numbers of known primes and of threads to use in the pre-seeding process by making appropriate performance measurements for different choices.

Additionally, there are some micro-optimizations you could implement to (probably) eke out a little speedup even from the serial version.  That's tangential to the question, so I will not go into specifics here, but you should easily find examples around the Net.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I really appreciate it. In order to avoid doing more works than necessary, is it better if I take out the line you focused on?

Comment: @SkipperLin, no, it is *not* better if you take out that line.  You do get some advantage from it.  My point there is that parallelization yields *much less* benefit for you than it might if the algorithm did not have the data dependency represented by that line. That contributes to the net performance degradation you asked about.  One of your better (really!) alternatives is to simply not parallelize.  I have updated this answer with a couple of others.