# Parallelizing for loop with unknown increment condition using OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am finding all primes using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. I attempted to parallelize this algorithm. However, speedup stops increasing after two threads!

[image: Speedup Graph]

My code is essentially two for loops. The outer for loop is the one increments the counter by an invariant (2). Within this loop, the counter is incremented by 2*x where x is unknown.

```
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (int k = 3; k <= sqrt_size; k = k+2) {
        for (int curPrime = k*k; curPrime <= size; curPrime += 2*k) marked[curPrime/2] = 1;
        while (marked[k/2]) k += 2; // Find following unmarked value (unknown amount)
   }
```

I think my lack of speedup past two threads is due to the unknown amount being added to the counter variable.
Should I make the counter shared, and then place the increment or entire while loop within a critical section?

Comment: Your code contains a race condition on `marked` as some thread can write into it (inner for loop) while others can read it (inner while loop). I think you cannot parallelize the outer loop that way. The final result is probably currently wrong.

Comment: Here's another answer for the same problem/issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634587/failed-performance-improvement-in-the-nested-for-loop-in-openmp/55635962#55635962

Comment: @CraigEstey surrounding this snippet, I implemented the suggestions posted in the answer he has.

Comment: @JérômeRichard how would I resolve this race condition? I found that parallelizing the inner for loop is most significant, so I can remove the outer for loop's pragma. Would I then just need to make the while loop a critical section?

Comment: Moving the `#pragma omp parallel for` just before the `curPrime` loop is fine. In this case you do not need a critical section since the while loop is outside the OpenMP section. The resulting code may be not efficient but it will be at least correct. I am curious of the resulting performance.

Comment: With just the parallel for before the inner for loop, I get a speedup of ~60% for a problem size of 1.5 billion. With both for loops parallelized, it's about the same as just the outer loop parallelized. I am guessing it is due to the race condition you mentioned.